# How to get username from user id in template

Tags: django

This is probably a simple answer but I cant figure it out. I have a comment system on my blog. I need to get the username from the user id.

I get the id from which is a fk to the users table

```
{{child_comment.parent_userdata_id}}
```

Usually when I need to do this I just user .username but it doesn't seem to work in this case

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get object data from the database is to fetch it on the server-side.

Unfortunately, you can't do that on the live HTML template.
Django template is just for evaluating the pre-existing context data for better use.

So, filtering the *username* from *user id* in views (backend) and passing it via the context into the template is the only (and probably the best) option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user login is required to comment, you can create a variable of user = request.user in your view function, now user variable has the instance of user  and pass it as context in template. It would look like this

views.py

```
def view_function(request):
    user = request.user 
    # do something
    context = {
        'user' : user,
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

template.html

```
<p>{{user.username}}</p>
```

[reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/)